# How to reload GameScene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a simple game and when the time is up the game is over. I have a restart button which currently just reloads the GameScene but for some reason my Nodes appear halfway down and halfway to the left of the screen. I can still use the full space of the screen to play the game though.

The images below show the game while working, end game state and then after reloading the GameScene.

I'm not sure how to fix this or what code to provide.

This is my function for reloading the GameScene:

```
func goToGameScene(){
    let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size) 
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0)
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.fill
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

[image: What the game should look like]

[image: End Game]

[image: After reloading the GameScene]

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` in your gameScene, print out `achorPoint`. It looks like it changes for the 2nd and subsequent loads.

Comment: Thank you but the anchor point appears to stay the same before and after I reload the GameScene

Comment: So the scene's anchorPoint doesn't change from (0, 0) or (0.5, 0.5). What about the itinial positions of the other sprites - do they change?

Comment: The anchorPoint goes from AnchorPoint(x: 0, y: 0) to AnchorPoint(x: 0, y: 0) according to the console. The initial position of the background, ad banner (that red 'X'), Score Label and time remaining label are moved. And then when the end screen is added, its position has the same problem.

Comment: OK - you'll have to check any code that moves those nodes. I think you can put a property observer on a nodes `position` property, which might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.fill
```

With:

```
gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
```

Or:

```
gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

You can also just completely copy the GameViewController code so you get something like this:

```
if let view = self.view {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
```

Just put that code where you want to reload the scene.

Comment: I just copied the GameViewController as you said and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: You just need if let scene... also setting up a view debugging options is not needed.